# Give intervals for the following

Tags: functions, interval-arithmetic

$\{ X \}$ is fractional part of $X$.

$[ X ]$ is greatest integer function (integral part of $X$)

$| X |$ is modulus of $X$

1)   $X^2 > \{ X \}$

2)  $X^2 > [ X ]$

3)  $X^2 ≥ 4$

4) $X^2 > | X |$

5) $[ X ] ≤ | X |$

Also can somebody please explain with the graph, it would become much easier to understand.

Regards

Comment: What is "fractional part"?  In particular, of a number like $-3/2$?

Comment: Given no. - greatest integer function for eg : in 4.5 => 4.5 - 4 = 1/2 is the fractional part